# create a Compound Predicate in coreData xcode iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nspredicate

HI i am working on the core data with 3 entities (Class,Students,ExamRecord) and their relations area as :

```
Class<------>> Students <------> ExamRecord
```

I created a predicate for fetching list of students for class 5th.

```
NSString * fmt2 = @"studentsToClass.className=%@";
NSPredicate * p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:fmt2,@"5th",nil];
```

with this i am getting all students of class 5th

Now i also want to apply another filter on the Students fetched.

Fetch students whose Exam Record "result" is "Pass".result is an attribute for student in ExamResult entity

How can i make use of Compound predicate in this ?

Please correct me if i am wrong

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use a compound predicate:

```
NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"studentsToClass.className = %@", @"5th"];
NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"studentsToExamRecord.result = %@", @"Pass"];
NSPredicate *p = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates: @[p1, p2]];
```

Or you simply combine the tests with "AND":

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"studentsToClass.className = %@ AND studentsToExamRecord.result = %@",
      @"5th", @"Pass"];
```

Note that the argument list of `predicateWithFormat` is not `nil`-terminated.
The number of arguments is determined by the number of format specifiers in the format
string.

Comment: @Fogmeister: I would love to know.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for your help but still I am not able to fetch the result for Student.My predicate becomes:   studentsToClass.className == "5th" AND studentsToExamRecord.result == "Pass"   PLease help and correct me where i am wrong

Comment: @sagar: Do you get an error or no results? Perhaps show how the entities are defined and how you create the objects. Do you get all objects if you omit the predicate?

Comment: if i apply  studentsToClass.className == "5th then i get all the students else no records are found

Comment: @sagar: But the predicate looks OK. Are you sure that the relationship  from Students to ExamRecord is set? Is the value of the "result" attribute really "Pass" or could it be lower-case?

Answer (score 2):

First, you shouldn't really call the `student - class` relation `studentsToClass`. The name of the relation should reflect what type of object is at the other end.

E.g.

In this case the `Student` relation to `Class` should be called `class` because the object there is a single `Class` entity.
The inverse relation should not be called `classToStudent` it should be called `students` because the object there is a `NSSet` of multiple `Students`.

**EDIT**

Just to add to this. The name of the relation should explain WHY it is there. We can see that the relation is from class to student but if you call it "classToStudent" it doesn't explain anything. Also, what if you have a second relation from class to student? What do you call that. If you call it `attendees` or `pupils` or `attendingStudents` etc.. it gives the relation meaning.

**SOLUTION**

In this example I'm going to call them how I would call them and you will see it makes it a bit easier to understand...

Anyway...

```
NSPredicate *classPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"class.className = %@", @"5th"];
NSPredicate *passPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"result.name = %@", @"Pass"];

NSCompoundPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[classPredicate, passPredicate]];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help   But still i cant fetch the student.My predicate becomes:    studentsToClass.className == "5th" AND studentsToExamRecord.result == "Pass" PLease help and correct me where i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

First, your quoted predicate is really already wrong. You should reference the managed object, not its property (i.e. not the `name` of the `Class`). It should be:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"class = %@", classObject];
```

Also, you should really choose more readable names for your variables and property. So, not `fmt2` but `formattingString`. Not `studentsToClass` but `form` ("class" is a special word in objective-C). You get the idea.

So your desired compound predicate is done like this (short version):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"class = %@ && record.result = %@",
         classObject, @"Pass"];
```

The complicated version, if you *really need* a higher level of abstraction (which I doubt):

```
classPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"class = %@", classObject]; 
resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"record.result = %@", @"Pass"];
finalPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
    @[classPredicate, resultPredicate]];
```

Comment: How to join two subpredicates into one if they are both optional, i.e. A OR B and not A AND B.

Comment: That would be a separate SOF question ;-).

Comment: Yes I found that:) It is done using orPredicateWithSubpredicates:

Answer (score 0):

Predicates can also be nested using compounded predicates (For **Swift**)

```
        let orPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .or, subpredicates: [date_1KeyPredicate, date_2KeyPredicate])

        let functionKeyPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "function_name = %@", self.title!)

        let andPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: [orPredicate, functionKeyPredicate])
```