# NSPredicate - Evaluate with two conditions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, nspredicate

I want to know how to evaluate NSString which satisfied two conditions using NSPredicate. For example how to check a string that should have atleast one upper case letter and atleast one number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this by myself. I used regular expression with predicate to solve this issue.

```
NSPredicate *pwdCheck = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", @"(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9]).*"];
bool isValid = [pwdCheck evaluateWithObject:@"99a99A3w"];
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use ANDing for two or more condition.

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
 NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];

 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fbUID = %@ AND birthDate = %d AND birthMonth = %d AND greetingYear = %d", uID, birthDate, birthMonth, greetingYear];

//NSLog(@"%@ :",predicate);
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

 NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

You can check more on NSPredicate [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html).

Comment: Hi.. your answer seems to be correct. But I was able to do it using reg ex in few lines of code. Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is:

```
NSCharacterSet *upperCaseCharacters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"];
NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {

    return ([evaluatedObject rangeOfCharacterFromSet:upperCaseCharacters].location != NSNotFound && [evaluatedObject rangeOfCharacterFromSet:numbers].location != NSNotFound);

}];

NSString *stringToEvaluate = @"aasad5D";

BOOL result = [predicate evaluateWithObject:stringToEvaluate];
```

Another solution is compound predicate, see this question for example how to use compound predicates [create a Compound Predicate in coreData xcode iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724068/create-a-compound-predicate-in-coredata-xcode-iphone).

Comment: Hi.. your answer seems to be correct. But I was able to do it using reg ex in few lines of code. Thanks for your help..